# Pi3b vs hostapd: invalid/unknown driver 'nl80211'

Tags: wifi, pi-3

I'm attempting to make my Pi3b into a wifi access point with Rasbian Jessie and hostapd, [following this tutorial](https://frillip.com/using-your-raspberry-pi-3-as-a-wifi-access-point-with-hostapd/) among others.

I've tried several different versions of `hostapd`, as suggested in the other tutorials, but I always get the error

```
Line 5: invalid/unknown driver 'nl80211'
```

Am I missing something?  Is the `driver=nl80211` inappropriate for the Pi3b's bcm43430?

Comment: I followed that recipe and it worked first time for me (Pi3).  I am using the hostapd that is returned from a sudo apt-get install hostapd.  What I'd suggest is to get a second SD card and burn a virgin Raspbian and on that, test the recipe in the tutorial without modifying anything else.  If that works, then we will know that something on your target image is "confused".

Comment: I must admit to having been skeptical, the install was only 2 hours old and I hadn't done much... but indeed that got things working.  Thanks for the nudge!  Very helpful to know that others with the same hardware have had success.

Answer (score 1):

Simply leave out the `driver=`, I'm running both 3Bs and 0Ws successfully in hostapd mode this way.

And **don't** run `raspi-update` unless explicitly told to do so due to a very specific kernel bug and the diagnosis points towards a fix that is only available yet via the testing kernels. This isn't the case here. The Wifi TOS bug shouldn't be a problem here, it typically manifests in stalled SSH sessions or NTP not synchronizing. And only then go out on the limb and do `raspi-update`, but be sure to make a working backup to another mSD card first, so you can swap that in in case the newer kernel and modules cause more issues than it does fix.

When using `raspi-update` you are installing test kernels that might break things. Hostapd runs fine on stock mainline kernels. I can't understand why people instruct others to run `raspi-update` when there isn't a good reason why, and they don't inform others what a `radpi-update` may cause and thus to be prepared...

Comment: `raspi-config` is the default configuration program for many options on Raspberry Pi. Do you mean `rpi-config` for kernel updates, right?

Comment: well spotted; I've corrected the text

Comment: It is neither `raspi-update` nor `rpi-config`, a little confusion here also by myself. The program to update the latest developed kernel version is named `rpi-update` and the  program to configure the Raspberry Pi is named `raspi-config`.